# regex capture content of {} only if no part is inside "" (and other encapsulators)

Tags: javascript, regex

are regular expressions even appropriate for this problem?
I'm trying to extract blocks of text surrounded by 'raw' curly braces. so anything surrounded by "" or **,"",~~,``, should be ignored entirely.
sample text:

```
{
"text1"
'text2'
*text3*
~text4~
`text5`
}
{
"half  broken1}{"
*half  broken2}{*
'half  broken3}{'
~half  broken4}{~
`half  broken5}{`
}
{
"{nested text1}"
'{nested text2}'
~{nested text3}~
*{nested text4}*
`{nested text5}`
}
{
"text1"
{
`text2`
}
}
```

expected output:

```
[
"\"text1\"
'text2'
*text3*
~text4~
`text5`",

"\"half  broken1}{\"
*half  broken2}{*
'half  broken3}{'
~half  broken4}{~
`half  broken5}{`",

"\"{nested text1}\"
'{nested text2}'
~{nested text3}~
*{nested text4}*
`{nested text5}`",

"\"text1\"
{
`text2`
}",
"`text2`"
]
```

I can target curly braces with:

```
/(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})/gm
```

but that eats the first } facing brace it finds to match. I have tried a few other strings, but so far - I don't know how to ignore {"}"} the first brace in this case.

(using js syntax for regex)

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/EODDXL/1

`` (?<=\{)(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\*[^*]*\*|~[^~]*~|`[^`]*`|{[^}]*}|[^}])*?(?=\}) ``

That's starting with what you had, but includes ignoring `"` followed by 0 or more `[^"]` followed by a `"`.  Then repeat this pattern for `'`, `*`, `~`, `` ` `` and `{}`.  This captures the outer groups only.  I'm not sure how exactly you'd get the expected output at the end, but this may get you in the right direction.